# When & where to initialize extern variables from arbitrary message return values?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, initialization, extern

The project I am working on stores some constant strings like this:
(.h)

```
extern NSURL *kURLLocationComputer;
```

And I need to initialize them as follows:
(.mm)

```
NSURL *kURLLocationComputer;

... {
      kURLLocationComputer = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"computer:///"];
... }
```

The problem is that they are used from many various places in the project, and they need to be initialized first. But since some of the initializations are complex (not constant), they can't be done inline.

**How should I ensure that they are initialized before being used?** I was thinking of adding a dummy class and initializing the variables in `+load`, but I don't think one is allowed to assume that the Cocoa library classes are working by that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, it turns out that **`__attribute__((constructor))` functions** are guaranteed to be called after `+load` is called for all classes. From the NSObject documentation on `+load`:

> The `load` message is sent to classes and categories that are both dynamically loaded and statically linked, but only if the newly loaded class or category implements a method that can respond.
>
> The order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. All initializers in any framework you link to.
> 2. All `+load` methods in your image.
> 3. All C++ static initializers and C/C++ `__attribute__(constructor)` functions in your image.
> 4. All initializers in frameworks that link to you.

Comment: The same documentation suggests that `+load` would work as well.

Comment: @PeterHosey That's true. Though in some cases you might have to be more careful as your other `+load` methods may not have been executed. (I realize that perhaps not many people have lots of `+load` methods in their code, but `__attribute__((constructor))` might be considered just a little safer. Of course if you have multiple `__attribute__((constructor))` functions you're in the same situation :) )

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you go for singleton class / Shared Instance.

That can be used as global variable throughout.